# How do i remove the quotes using my code?

Tags: python

Basically, can I know how to add `quote_none` to my code? I am using Python 3.7. I am trying to keep it as simple as possible.

```
csvFile = csv.reader(open("cats.csv",'r'))
header = next(csvFile)
index = 1
print (header)
print("")
for row in csvFile :
  if row[1] >= "35" :
    print (row)
    index +=1
```

This is what I got:

```
1 ['Oliver', '12', 'HOPE']
2 ['Leo', '16', 'SPCA', '']
3 ['Milo', '13', 'ISPCA', ']
4 ['Jack', '12', 'SPCA', ']
5 ['George', '14', 'HOPE']
6 ['Bella', '10', 'FFF', ']
7 ['Cleo', '14', 'SPCA', '']
8 ['Nala', '16', 'ISPCA', '']
9 ['Teddy', '12', 'SPCA', ']
10 ['Zeus', '16', 'SPCA', '']
11 ['Louie', '14', 'LOVS', '']
12 ['Apollo', '11', 'FFF', '' ]
13 ['George', '10', 'SPCA', '']
14 ['Ziggy', '11', 'ISPCA', ']
```

Expected results:

```
1 ['Oliver,12,HOPE']
2 ['Leo,16,SPCA']
3 ['Charlie,18,SPCA']
4 ['Milo,13,ISPCA']
5 ['Jack,12,SPCA']
6 ['George,14']
7 ['Simon,22,SPCA']
8 ['Loki,24,SPCA']
9 ['Simba,23,SPCA']
```

Comment: Looks like you want to concatenate the fields in each row (google "concatenate"). I don't understand how you decide which rows to suppress, can you [edit] your question and clarify?

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly get this output from the above code given that you compare strings in `if row[1] >= "35"` and neither of printed strings (row[1]) is would satisfy the if condition, e.g. `if "12" >= "35"` would be evaluated `False`

Comment: in addition to my previous comment, it looks we have XY problem here. The quotes you see when print each row are not from the file, i.e. they would not be affected by csv.QUOTE_NONE. You use csv module, so row is a list of strings, i.e. you print list of strings. And I doubt you actually want the square brackets too. What is your actual goal?

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`:

```
lst = ['Oliver', '12', 'HOPE']
print([','.join(lst)])
```

So, in your example I guess this would be:

```
print([','.join(row)])
```